# Automatically change the name of destination folder based on Google Form answer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have minimal experience coding, but I'm trying to alter this snippet to change the destination folder's name to a question response in my google form.  The code works as intended and creates a folder for each individual response's file upload, but the folder's name is the response ID.  I see where it does that in the code, but I'm unsure how to change it to the content of an answer within the form response.  I want to change the folder name to be created as the response to a question that asks users their name.

```
const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const subfolderName = response.getId();
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

I'm sorry in advance for my inexperience.  I'm trying to understand App script better this summer, so as an adjacent question, if anyone has any resources I can use to help me, that would be amazing as well.

Comment: Personally I wound't use the form onFormSubmit.  I'd use the spreadsheet onFormSubmit.  What your looking for is in e.namedValues and e.values.  One is object and the other is array.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create new folder by retrieving the folder name from the question, and put the uploaded files to the created folder.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, at first, add new question for inputting the folder name to Google Form.

  - As a test, the title of this question is `subfolderName`.
- In your script, in order to retrieve the file IDs, `filter`, `map` and `reduce` are used. In this modification, in order to retrieve the file IDs and the folder name, I use `reduce`. By this, I thought that the process cost can be reduced a little.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you test this modified script, please confirm whether the question for inputting the folder name as the title of `subfolderName` again.

##### From:

```
const files = response
  .getItemResponses()
  // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
  .filter(
    (itemResponse) =>
      itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
  )
  .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
  // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
  .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
```

##### To:

```
const {files, subfolderName} = response
  .getItemResponses()
  .reduce((o, e) => {
    const item = e.getItem();
    if (item.getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD") {
      o.files = o.files.concat(e.getResponse());
    } else if (item.getTitle() === "subfolderName") {
      o.subfolderName = e.getResponse();
    }
    return o;
  }, {files: [], subfolderName: ""});
```

- By above modification, `files` and `subfolderName` are the file IDs and the folder name, respectively.
- In this sample, `subfolderName` is used for the title of the question for inputting the folder name on Google Form. When you want to modify this, please modify `subfolderName` of `if (item.getTitle() === "subfolderName")` for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)